# Preview's "tightpage" is too tight

Tags: packages, preview

I'm using the `preview` package to generate tightly boxed maths environments. Unfortunately, it seems to be clipping out the edges (some subscripts are not showing in the final pdf). Is there a way to put a 'buffer' around the preview box, so that an extra few pixels on each side are left in?

Comment: From the manual: psfixbb Dvips determines the bounding boxes from the material in the DVI file
it understands. Lots of PostScript specials are not part of that. Since the
TEX boxes do not make it into the DVI file, but merely characters, rules and
specials do, Dvips might include far too small areas. The option psfixbb will
include /dev/null as a graphic file in the ultimate upper left and lower right
corner of the previewed box. This will make Dvips generate an appropriate
bounding box.

Comment: @JPi I added the psfixbb option to preview, and turned off some pdf-only features (hyperref was throwing an error, but it's not essential to me). The resulting dvi leaves a lot of white space in some places (that's fine) and clips out a lot of the text in other places (less fine). Running that through dvips appears to print each page onto A4 pages (leaving a lot of white space, with the desired content in the bottom left corner).

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax % approximation of π accurate up to 6 decimal places.
%\PreviewEnvironment{align*}

\begin{document}
\preview
$
\displaystyle
\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)
$
\endpreview
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *standalone* package to tightly crop the page to math content:

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth=1000pt,border=0.5]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$$ f(x)=x^2 $$
\end{document}
```

It has the `border` option that adds space around cropped content. You can even add space to each side separately:

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth=1000pt,border={0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0}]{standalone}
```